# I have some trouble with the delimiter

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, runtime-error

```
    import java.util.*;
    import java.io.*;
    import java.*;          

    public class b {

   static void lireBddParcs(String nomFichier) throws IOException
    {
        LinkedHashMap parcMap = new LinkedHashMap<Parc,Collection<Manege>> ();
        boolean existeFichier = true;        
        FileReader fr = null;

        try
        {
            fr = new FileReader (nomFichier);
        }        
        catch(java.io.FileNotFoundException erreur)
        {
            System.out.println("Probleme rencontree a l'ouverture du fichier" + nomFichier);
            existeFichier = false;
        }        
        if (existeFichier)
        {
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(nomFichier).useDelimiter("\t");        
            while (scan.hasNextLine())
            {        
                   String nom = scan.next();
                   String ville = scan.next();
                   String etat = scan.next();
                   Parc p = new Parc(nom, ville, etat);
                   parcMap.put(p, null);        
            }
            scan.close();        
        }
    }

        public static void main(String[] args)  throws IOException
        {
          lireBddParcs("parcs.txt");        
        }
    }
```

parc.txt contains:

```
Great America   Chicago Illinois
Magic mountain  Los Ageles  Californie
Six Flags over Georgia  Atlanta Georgie
Darien Lake Buffalo New York
La Ronde    Montreal    Quebec
The Great Escape    Lake Georges    New York
Six Flags New Orleans   New Orleans Louisiane
Elitch Gardens  Denver  Colorado
Six Flags over Texas    Arlington   Texas
Six Flags New England   Springfield Massachusetts
Six Flags America   Washington  D.C.
Great Adventure Jackson New Jersey
```

I get this:

```
--------------------Configuration: <Default>--------------------
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:907)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1416)
    at b.lireBddParcs(b.java:54)
    at b.main(b.java:94)
```

I have been trying to fix the program for a good 3 hours. And God I am dumb. I don't know what's wrong with the program!

Comment: Do you think you could get rid of a little of that whitespace for us? We usually appreciate it if you try to make it easy for us to read and understand your code, so it's kind of to your advantage to do this.

Comment: Also, put in some `System.out.println(...)` statements in your code to see what Strings your code is tripping over, especially just before the spot where the exception gets thrown. *Also* you shouldn't check Scanner for `hasNextLine()` and then call `next()`, the `hasNextXXX()` should match the `nextXXX()` that follows it, and it should be a one to one kind of deal.

Comment: You're eligible for the empty-line-award.

Comment: parcs.txt
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
 at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:907)
 at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1416)
 at b.lireBddParcs(b.java:55)
 at b.main(b.java:95)

Comment: I don't know why it's returning the name of the text file!!!

Comment: `Atlanta Georgie`  Showing results for Atlanta *Georgia* ;) `Los Ageles  Californie` 'ditto' - Los *Angeles California*.

Answer (score 0):

You're passing in the file name String not a File object itself, and so that is all your Scanner is "scanning". Fix that by first creating a File from the file String, and then passing that into the Scanner.

So  not,

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(nomFichier)
```

but rather

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File(nomFichier))
```

And next time, please make the edits to your question that we've requested. We're volunteers and it is your responsibility to not make it unnecessarily difficult to understand your question and answer it.

Comment: Sorry, didn't know how to get rid of the white space.

Comment: Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("nomFichier"))

Comment: @Scanner, no, that's not right. Your file is not called "nomFichier" but the nomFichier variable holds the file name.

Comment: @Questions: the edit link is at the bottom of your original post, right between "link" and "close".

Comment: when i do lireBddParcs("parcs.txt"); doesn't the name of the file get sent into nomFichier?

Comment: Yes it does, but it's only a String, and if you construct a Scanner with a String it will scan the String. It has no idea that you mean it's a File.

Comment: --------------------Configuration: <Default>--------------------
Great America
Los Ageles
Georgie
Darien Lake
Montreal
New York
Six Flags New Orleans
Denver
Texas
Six Flags New England
Washington
New Jersey
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
 at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:907)
 at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1416)
 at b.lireBddParcs(b.java:55)
 at b.main(b.java:95)

Process completed.

Comment: can i use two delimiters at the same time, it seems some information are separated by white spaces.

Comment: @Questions: yes you can use two *Scanners* at the same time, one to read in a line and another to analyze the line, each one using its own delimiter.